# Is it possible to see to whom deleted messages were sent from my hacked account?

Tags: facebook

My Facebook account was hacked and some bad messages were sent from my id to an unknown person.

After sending the messages, the hacker deleted them. Can I get the list of persons to whom a message was sent from my Facebook id?

Comment: @pnuts Our edits collided, could you propose it again?

Answer (score 1):

From your side, no, this will not be possible.

However you can ask your friends what the message said since deleting a message (messages from inbox) deletes it from only one side.

If this message is a post then no it will not be possible to retrieve it.